# Check if more than two date ranges overlap

Tags: javascript, date, compare, range

I have multiple date ranges. I want to check if they are overlapping in javascript. When there are only two it is easy, I use:

```
if(start_times1 <= end_times2 && end_times1 >= start_times2) {}
```

But what is the formula when there are more than 2 date ranges?

Comment: ...same idea, wouldn't it be?

Comment: But how? I don't know the exact amount of dates. It can be 2 but also 3 or 4

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use nested `for` loops with `arguments`

```
function dateRangeOverlaps(a_start, a_end, b_start, b_end) {
    if (a_start <= b_start && b_start <= a_end) return true; // b starts in a
    if (a_start <= b_end   && b_end   <= a_end) return true; // b ends in a
    if (b_start <  a_start && a_end   <  b_end) return true; // a in b
    return false;
}
function multipleDateRangeOverlaps() {
    var i, j;
    if (arguments.length % 2 !== 0)
        throw new TypeError('Arguments length must be a multiple of 2');
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length - 2; i += 2) {
        for (j = i + 2; j < arguments.length; j += 2) {
            if (
                dateRangeOverlaps(
                    arguments[i], arguments[i+1],
                    arguments[j], arguments[j+1]
                )
            ) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Because you talked about _dates_ I put the word _date_ in the names of these functions, but really they'd work for any _Number_ range.

Comment: @PaulS. thanks for this solution, it has really saved my time today!

Comment: How do we implement this? Where is the function call that starts this off?

Comment: how can to combine same overlapping dates?

Comment: it's not a bad idea to comment your code instead of just type some code lines

Comment: @Akashlal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments --- if you're doing this in modern code, use a rest parameter instead; `multipleDateRangeOverlaps(...args) { /* ... */ }` and replace uses of `arguments` with `args`

Answer (score 16):

Here is refined version of what Paul posted:

- Added filter and null check to allow any number of entries
- Changed the logic so that it can be applied on an array. Eg: [{"from": value, "to": value}]
- Adjusted overlap check to allow times having end and start as same

Script:

```
function dateRangeOverlaps(a_start, a_end, b_start, b_end) {
    if (a_start < b_start && b_start < a_end) return true; // b starts in a
    if (a_start < b_end   && b_end   < a_end) return true; // b ends in a
    if (b_start <  a_start && a_end   <  b_end) return true; // a in b
    return false;
}

function multipleDateRangeOverlaps(timeEntries) {
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    let timeIntervals = timeEntries.filter(entry => entry.from != null && entry.to != null && entry.from.length === 8 && entry.to.length === 8);

    if (timeIntervals != null && timeIntervals.length > 1)
    for (i = 0; i < timeIntervals.length - 1; i += 1) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < timeIntervals.length; j += 1) {
                if (
                dateRangeOverlaps(
            timeIntervals[i].from.getTime(), timeIntervals[i].to.getTime(),
            timeIntervals[j].from.getTime(), timeIntervals[j].to.getTime()
                    )
                ) return true;
            }
        }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You save my day

Comment: You might need to use <= in dateRangeOverlaps depending on your data context

Answer (score 5):

Below code comes from my project, maybe it will help you:

```js
function dateRangeOverlaps(startDateA, endDateA, startDateB, endDateB) {

    if ((endDateA < startDateB) || (startDateA > endDateB)) {
        return null
    }

    var obj = {};
    obj.startDate = startDateA <= startDateB ? startDateB : startDateA;
    obj.endDate = endDateA <= endDateB ? endDateA : endDateB;

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [areIntervalsOverlapping](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/areIntervalsOverlapping) function from [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), the "*modern JavaScript date utility library*".

You just have to pass the two dates as arguments to the function, and it will return true or false depending if the two dates overlaps or not.

#### Example

Check this example from their documentation:

```
areIntervalsOverlapping(
  { start: new Date(2014, 0, 10), end: new Date(2014, 0, 20) },
  { start: new Date(2014, 0, 17), end: new Date(2014, 0, 21) }
)
//=> true
```

This example above returned `true` because the two dates overlaps. Note that the `0` number (the second argument) in `Date(2014, 0, 10)` represents the month of January.

You can also use this `areIntervalsOverlapping` function to check if other time intervals (like hours in the same day) overlaps, because in JavaScript a `Date` object also considers hours.

#### Installation

If, for example, you are using Node.js (or any framework that uses it), you just have to install date-fns with

```
npm install date-fns --save
```

And then import the desired functions inside your JavaScript code like:

```
import { areIntervalsOverlapping } from "date-fns";
```

Of course date-fns is not limited to Node.js. You can use it inside any JavaScript project.

Answer (score 1):

//storing existing dates for comparison

```
public multipleExistingDates=[
         {startDate:'02/03/2020 05:00:00',endDate:'02/03/2020 05:30:00'},
         {startDate:02/04/2020 05:00:00'',endDate:'02/05/2020 05:00:00'},]
```

/*The date to be compared with existing dates to check if the new date is overlapping with existing dates*/

```
public checkOverlappingDsates(startDate:Date, endDate:Date):boolean{
  return this.multipleExistingDates.some((elem)=>{
       return( !((moment(endDate).diff(moment(elem.startDate))) < 0 || 
              (moment(startDate).diff(moment(elem.endDate))) > 0;})
```

Note: If the date is overlapping, the function return true else false. Also , you would need to install moment for date comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we use moment and moment-range, is it not supported across all browsers?

```js
window['moment-range'].extendMoment(moment);

const events1 = [{
    "Date": "05/15/2021",
    "EndTime": "17:00",
    "StartTime": "16:00"
},
{
    "Date": "05/15/2021",
    "EndTime": "18:00",
    "StartTime": "17:00"
},
{
    "Date": "05/15/2021",
    "EndTime": "18:45",
    "StartTime": "17:45"
}
];

const events2 = [{
    "Date": "05/15/2021",
    "EndTime": "17:00",
    "StartTime": "16:00"
},
{
    "Date": "05/15/2021",
    "EndTime": "18:00",
    "StartTime": "17:00"
},
{
    "Date": "05/15/2021",
    "EndTime": "19:45",
    "StartTime": "18:45"
}
];

function checkOverlap(timeSegments) {

    var overlap = timeSegments
        .map(r =>
            timeSegments.filter(q => q != r).map(q =>
                moment.range(
                    moment(q.Date + " " + q.StartTime),
                    moment(q.Date + " " + q.EndTime)
                ).overlaps(
                    moment.range(
                        moment(r.Date + " " + r.StartTime),
                        moment(r.Date + " " + r.EndTime)
                    )
                )
            )
        );

    console.log(overlap.map(x => x.includes(true)).includes(true));
}

checkOverlap(events1);
checkOverlap(events2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-range/4.0.2/moment-range.js"></script>
```

Comment: One could even use its successor luxon with the built-in `Interval` type.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't be too hard to do recursively. Make a method `overlap` which returns the overlapping daterange for two dates. Then in your `hasOverlap(list dates)` method, if the list is two items, it's simple, else, return `hasoverlap(overlap(dates[0], dates[1]), rest of list)`

Comment: A _range_ is always _2D_, a list is _1D_ but can have unknown length, You have enough knowns to do this without recursion

Answer (score -1):

No matter the language, the basic logic to see if two date ranges overlap is:

```
max(range_1_start, range_2_start) <= min(range_1_end, range_2_end)
```

In JavaScript syntax, that might look like this:

```
function doDatesOverlap(start_1,end_1,start_2,end_2){
    return Math.max(start_1,start_2) <= Math.min(end_1,end_2);
}

var start_1 = new Date('01/01/2023');
var end_1 = new Date('01/31/2023');
var start_2 = new Date('01/15/2023');
var end_2 = new Date('02/15/2023');

if(doDatesOverlap(start_1,end_1,start_2,end_2)){
    console.log('They overlap!');
}
```

Comment: The question is about *more* than two date ranges overlapping.