# Use JavaScript to compare time ranges

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs, angular-moment

I have a collection of time ranges in the form of Date objects. I need to compare those time ranges against a new time range to make sure I don't add a time range that overlaps or duplicates an existing time range.

Here's an example of the collection.

```
var timeSlots = [
    {
        BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:00 AM"),
        EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:45 AM")
    },
    {
        BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:00 AM"),
        EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:45 AM")
    },
    {
        BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:50 AM"),
        EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 10:30 AM")
    }
];
```

In the previous example, the date part of the dates don't matter. The times do.

If I have an new time range object that begins at 9:30 AM, I need to be able to detect that.

This is inside of an AngularJS app and it has access to both MomentJS and Angular Moment.

How can I take a new time slot object and ensure that it won't conflict with the others that exist?

```
// building off of the previous example
var newTimeSlot = newDate("10/25/2015 9:00 AM");
if (!conflictingTime(newTimeSlot)) {
    // then run my code
}

function conflictingTime(time) {
    // how do I do this?
}
```

Comment: Convert the stamps to _Date_ then you can treat them as integers, look here for more http://stackoverflow.com/a/22785208/1615483

Comment: Those time stamps really are date objects. I've updated the question.

Comment: moment.js has comparison methods ... read the docs. Then use array methods to check what alredy exists

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

Comment: If you are using a date library, then you should be using that to parse the strings, not *Date.parse*. There is no reason to expect an ambiguous string like "10/25/2015 8:00 AM" will be parsed correctly otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is for an open source project, I was hoping that someone here likes SO points enough to come up with a more "best practice" or more elegant solution than what I did.  I guess everyone in the comments hates SO points though.

So here's my solution.

```
angular.forEach($scope.timeSlots, function (timeSlot, index) {
    var beginTimeHasIssue = ($scope.timeSlot.BeginTime >= timeSlot.BeginTime && $scope.timeSlot.BeginTime <= timeSlot.EndTime);
    var endTimeHasIssue = ($scope.timeSlot.EndTime >= timeSlot.BeginTime && $scope.timeSlot.EndTime <= timeSlot.EndTime);

    if (beginTimeHasIssue || endTimeHasIssue) {
        hasError = true;
        $scope.HasTimeSlotError = true;
        return;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is as suggested, however it doesn't seem robust, e.g. if there are no current slots the *forEach* won't do much. Also, it goes all the way to the end rather than stopping once it's found a slot. Consider the following:

```js
var timeSlots = [
  {BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:00 AM"),
   EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:45 AM")},
  {BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:00 AM"),
   EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:45 AM")},
  {BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:50 AM"),
   EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 10:30 AM")}
];

/*  @param   {Object} slot - object with BeginTime and EndTime date objects
 **  @returns {Boolean} true if slot fits, otherwise false
 */
function slotFits(slot) {
  if (timeSlots.length == 0) return true; // If no slots, must fit
  return timeSlots.some(function(s, i) {
    return (i == 0 && slot.EndTime <= s.BeginTime) || // slot is before all others
      (s.EndTime <= slot.BeginTime && !timeSlots[i + 1]) || // slot is after all others
      (s.EndTime <= slot.BeginTime && timeSlots[i + 1].BeginTime >= slot.EndTime) // Slot between others
  });
}

[{BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 7:00 AM"),  // before all, true
  EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:00 AM")},
 {BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 10:30 AM"),  // after all, true
  EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 11:00 AM")},
 {BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:45 AM"),  // between 0 and 1, true
  EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:00 AM")},
 {BeginTime: new Date("10/25/2015 8:45 AM"),  // Overlap 1, false
  EndTime: new Date("10/25/2015 9:15 AM")}
].forEach(function(slot, i) {
  console.log('Slot ' + i + ': ' + slotFits(slot));
});
```

This could also be optimised to stop once it's passed all chance of finding a slot, requires two more lines of code. You should be able to adapt this to your angular code.

PS. I would not usually create Dates this way using a string (i.e. using the built-in parser for non-standard strings), but it's sufficient for this example. The Dates really should be created using something like:

```js
var date = moment('10/25/2015 9:15 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm Z').toDate();

console.log(date.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `timeSlots[i+1].BeginTime` is undefined.

Comment: @user1027620 - if that's the case, it’s testing the last range and the previous line applies and would have returned *true*. If any test returns *true*, the function returns *true*, otherwise it returns *false*.

Comment: So even with the error, the function still works properly?

Comment: @user1027620—there is no error. `timeSlots[i + 1]` is tested before `timeSlots[i + 1].BeginTime` is reached, so if it's *undefined*, the next test isn't executed. And even if it is, `timeSlots[i + 1].BeginTime` would resolve to *undefined* and `timeSlots[i + 1].BeginTime >= slot.EndTime` would resolve to *false*, which is consistent with the logic and certainly not an error. The test could be more specific, e.g. `typeof timeSlots[i + 1] == 'undefined'`, but I can't see the benefit of that. Simple type conversion to boolean in condition expressions is extremely common in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
   addTimeSlot=function(newtimeSlot){
        var beginTimeHasIssue = false;
        var endTimeHasIssue = false;
        timeSlots.forEach(function (timeSlot, index) {
            if( newtimeSlot.BeginTime >= timeSlot.BeginTime &&  newtimeSlot.EndTime <= timeSlot.EndTime ) {
                 console.log('falls inbetween');
                endTimeHasIssue = true;
            } 
            if( newtimeSlot.BeginTime <= timeSlot.BeginTime &&  newtimeSlot.EndTime >= timeSlot.EndTime) {
                 console.log('falls inbetween');
                beginTimeHasIssue = true;
            }      
        });
        if (beginTimeHasIssue || endTimeHasIssue) {
            console.log('error');
            return;
        } else {
            timeSlots.push(newtimeSlot)
            console.log('saved');
        }
        if (timeSlots.length == 0) {
          timeSlots.push(newtimeSlot);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little more context would be helpful.