# Find all pairs of workers who worked in the same period as a team by given start date and end date for each worker

Tags: javascript, algorithm

my task is to find all pairs worked together and for how many days with JS for my react app.
The input data is text file with lines. Each line contains nameOfTheWorker, nameOfTheProject, dateOfStart (YYYY-MM-DD), dateOfEnd (YYYY-MM-DD)
Here is example:

```
John, ASD, 2019-03-05, 2020-03-25
Martin, ASD, 2020-03-02, 2020-03-6
Frank, ASD, 2020-03-20, 2020-03-25
Frank, OI9, 2017-03-07, 2020-03-25,
Simeon, proectX, 2018-07-22, 2020-01-04
Mileena, proectX, 2020-01-01, 2021-02-03
```

I need a function which make pairs of all people worked on the same project in the same time and calculate how many days the two persons worked together. In the example the result is that John and Frank worked together 5 days on project ASD because John and Frank working together in period 2020-03-20 - 2020-03-25 . No more pairs.
Can you help me writing that function in Javascript?

Here is what I tried:

```
 let from,to;
let daysArr = []

let filteredEmployees = []
let combinedObjArr = []
let arrFinal = []
let sortedAscending = []

//filtering employees who worked on same project
const lookup = arrFinal.reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e.projectId] = ++a[e.projectId] || 0;
    return a;
  }, {});
  
  filteredEmployees = arrFinal.filter(e => lookup[e.projectId])

  

    for(let i=0;i<filteredEmployees.length;i++){
    
        from = moment(filteredEmployees[i].dateFrom,"YYYY-MM-DD");
        to =  moment(filteredEmployees[i].dateTo, "YYYY-MM-DD");
        daysArr.push(to.diff(from,"days"))
        combinedObjArr[i] = Object.assign(filteredEmployees[i],{workedDays:daysArr[i]})
    }
    sortedAscending = combinedObjArr.sort((a,b)=>{
        const empA = a.workedDays;
        const empB = b.workedDays;
        let comparison = 0;

        if(empA>empB){
            comparison = -1;
        }else{
            comparison = 1;
        }
        return comparison
    })

    twoEmployeesArr.push(sortedAscending[0],sortedAscending[1]);
```

})

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: I wasted a lot of hours but still nothing, that's why I'm asking for help here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784883/check-if-more-than-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: Show what you tried..... People are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Ok, I will share what I tried.

Comment: I think if I convert any date to days, it will be easier to compare

Comment: Are you excluding one end of your range?  [`03-20`, `03-21`, `03-22`, `03-23`, `03-24`, `03-25`] contains six days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overall Structure

I'm assuming that we want to convert your input into something like this:

```
[ 
  {proj: 'ASD', people: ['John', 'Martin'], overlappingDays: 5},
  {proj: 'ASD', people: ['John', 'Frank'], overlappingDays: 6},
  {proj: 'proectX', people: ['Simeon', 'Mileena'], overlappingDays: 4}
]
```

Let's break the problem down into smaller steps.

The first thing we would need to do is to parse your input into an array of structures like

```js
{name: 'John', proj: 'ASD', start: '2019-03-05', stop: '2020-03-25'}
```

So we probably need a `parse` function for that.

Then we might turn them into arrays of those operating on the same project.  There's good reason to try to make this reasonably generic, so we might write a `group` a function which takes a function that generates a key and returns a function which takes an array and returns an array containing one array for each group generated.

(This is easier to understand with an example:

> ```js
> group (n => n % 10) ([33, 21, 68, 23, 1, 11, 87, 43, 13, 3])
> //=> [[21, 1, 11], [33, 23, 43, 13, 3], [87], [68]]
> ```

We group all those that end in `1` separate from those that end in `3`, versus those that end in `7`, and those that end in `8`, by using the remainder function (`%`).  We shouldn't read much into the order of these results, as it would be more logical if they came in the order `[[33, 23, 43, 13, 3], [21, 1, 11], [68], [87]]`, but there are some odd JS property sorting issues with small integers.)

Then we could combine all pairs of elements from each group into its own little structure.  So we would need an `allPairs` function that would work, for instance, like this:

```js
allPairs (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']) 
//=> [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd'], ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'd']]
```

These no longer have to be grouped by their project, so we would probably `flatMap` this function over our previously grouped collection.

Now we have an array of pairs, such as

```
[
  [
    {name: 'John', proj: 'ASD', start: '2019-03-05', stop: '2020-03-25'},
    {name: 'Martin', proj: 'ASD', start: '2020-03-02', stop: '2020-03-6'}
  ],
  //... John and Frank, Martin and Frank, Simeon and Mileena
]
```

To calculate the number of overlapping days, there could be many techniques.  One possibility would be to convert each `start`-`end` range into an array of dates, then find the intersection between the two sets for a given pair of people, and finally returning the count of that overlap.

To do that we would need a `getDays` function that worked like:

```js
getDays ('2021-07-28', '2021-08-03')
//=> ['2021-07-28', '2021-07-29', '2021-07-30', '2021-07-31', 
//    '2021-08-01', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-03']
```

and an `intersect`/`overlap` function which collects all the elements in common between two arrays.

A final step would simply run `filter` to remove all those values for which there turns out to be no overlap.

If we had all that, then our implementation of your main function might look like this:

```js
const findOverlaps = (input) => group (x => x.proj) (parse (input)) 
  .flatMap (allPairs) 
  .map (([a, b]) => ({
    proj: a.proj,
    people: [a.name, b.name],
    overlappingDays: intersection (getDays (a .start, a .end), getDays (b .start, b .end)) .length,
  }))
  .filter (({overlappingDays}) => overlappingDays > 0)
```

But of course, this requires having `parse`, `group`, `allPairs`, `intersection` and `getDays` functions.  All of those except for `getDays` are relatively straightforward.  `getDays` will still take some work.  So let's do the same breakdown for `getDays`.

### Handling dates

Javascripts date handling is a bit of a mess, which is why you often hear suggestions to use `moment`, `date-fns` or `date-fp` to do your date processing.   Here we try a different approach, treating dates as either ISO strings such as `2021-07-26` or as year-month-day arrays of numbers, such as `[2021, 7, 26]`.

We can write a `dateRange` function which works like this:

```js
dateRange ([2020, 3, 2], [2020, 3, 6]) 
//=> [[2020, 3, 2], [2020, 3, 3], [2020, 3, 4], [2020, 3, 5], [2020, 3, 6]]
```

and the wrapper function `getDays`, which converts the inputs `2020-03-02` and `2020-03-6` into the above inputs and then convert the outputs back into this format.  The wrapper is simple enough, but the `dateRange` function still takes a bit of work.  With a helper function to return the number of days in a month (using the year and month to handle leap years in February), which itself depends upon a `isLeapYear` function, as well as a simple `range` function that does the obvious, (`range (3, 12) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`), we can write it recursively like this:

```js
const dateRange = ([y1, m1, d1], [y2, m2, d2]) => 
  y1 > y2 
    ? []
  : y1 < y2
    ? [
         ... dateRange ([y1, m1, d1], [y1, 12, 31]),
         ... dateRange ([y1 + 1, 1, 1], [y2, m2, d2])
      ]
  : m1 > m2
    ? []
  : m1 < m2
    ? [
         ... dateRange ([y1, m1, d1], [y1, m1, daysInMonth (y1) (m1)]),
         ... dateRange ([y1, m1 + 1, 1], [y2, m2, d2])
      ]

  : range (d1, d2) .map (d => [y1, m1, d])
```

We first check if the end year is before the start year.  If it is, there are no dates to include.  Then we check if it's after the start year.  If it is, we break into two calls, one for the start day through the end of the year and one for the beginning of the next year through the end day.  If it's not, then we know that the years are the same, and we do the same thing with the month, except that we have to actually calculate the last day of the month with our helper function.  Finally, if the months are the same, we return a simple range of days from the start day to the end day in the current year and month.

There are many variants of this possible, but this is conceptually fairly simple.

### Altogether

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  Array .from ({length: hi - lo + 1}, (_, i) => lo + i)
const intersection = (xs, ys) => 
  xs .filter (x => ys .includes (x))
const allPairs = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  x == undefined ? [] : xs .map (y => [x, y]) .concat (allPairs (xs))
const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn(x)) => ({...a, [k]: [...(a[k] || []), x]}), {}))

const isLeapYear = (y) => 
  (y % 400 == 0) || (y % 100 !== 0 && y % 4 == 0)
const daysInMonth = (y) => (m) => 
  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [m - 1] + (m == 2 && isLeapYear (y) ? 1 : 0)
const fromIso = (date) =>
  date .split ('-') .map (Number)
const toIso = (y) => (m) => (d) => 
  `${y}-${String (m) .padStart (2, '0')}-${String (d) .padStart (2, '0')}`
const dateRange = ([y1, m1, d1], [y2, m2, d2]) => 
  y1 > y2 
    ? []
  : y1 < y2
    ? [... dateRange ([y1, m1, d1], [y1, 12, 31]), ... dateRange ([y1 + 1, 1, 1], [y2, m2, d2])]
  : m1 > m2
    ? []
  : m1 < m2
    ? [
        ... dateRange ([y1, m1, d1], [y1, m1, daysInMonth (y1) (m1)]), 
        ... dateRange ([y1, m1 + 1, 1], [y2, m2, d2])
      ]
  : range (d1, d2) .map (d => [y1, m1, d])

const getDays = (start, end) =>
  dateRange (fromIso (start), fromIso (end)) 
    .map (([y, m, d]) => toIso (y) (m) (d))



const parse = (input) =>
  input .split ('\n') 
    .filter (Boolean) 
    .map (s => s.split (', '))
    .map (([name, proj, start, end]) => ({name, proj, start, end}))

const findOverlaps = (input) => group (x => x.proj) (parse (input)) 
  .flatMap (allPairs) 
  .map (([a, b]) => ({
    proj: a.proj,
    people: [a.name, b.name],
    overlappingDays: intersection (getDays (a.start, a.end), getDays(b.start, b.end)) .length,
  }))
  .filter (({overlappingDays}) => overlappingDays > 0)


const input = `
John, ASD, 2019-03-05, 2020-03-25
Martin, ASD, 2020-03-02, 2020-03-6
Frank, ASD, 2020-03-20, 2020-03-25
Frank, OI9, 2017-03-07, 2020-03-25,
Simeon, proectX, 2018-07-22, 2020-01-04
Mileena, proectX, 2020-01-01, 2021-02-03
` 

console .log (findOverlaps (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Extension

This makes the assumption that each worker's time is captured by a single record.  We should consider what happens if we added this record to the input:

```
Mileena, proectX, 2019-05-11, 2019-05-15
```

This five-day record does not overlap with Mileena's other record, but does overlap with Simeon's.  Our final output should include something like:

```
 {proj: 'proectX', people: ['Simeon', 'Mileena'], overlappingDays: 9}
```

That would take a little reworking of our main function to combine the elements in our project grouping by the person's name.  But we can use almost all the same infrastructure as before, adding only a `unique` function to remove duplicates.

You can expand this snippet to see it in action:

```js
const range = (lo) => (hi) => 
  Array .from ({length: hi - lo + 1}, (_, i) => lo + i)
const overlap = (xs, ys) => 
  xs .filter (x => ys .includes (x))
const allPairs = ([x, ...xs]) => 
  x == undefined ? [] : xs .map (y => [x, y]) .concat (allPairs (xs))
const group = (fn) => (xs) =>
  Object .values (xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn(x)) => ({...a, [k]: [...(a[k] || []), x]}), {}))
const unique = (xs) =>
  [... new Set (xs)]

const isLeapYear = (y) => 
  (y % 400 == 0) || (y % 100 !== 0 && y % 4 == 0)
const daysInMonth = (y) => (m) => 
  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] [m - 1] + (m == 2 && isLeapYear (y) ? 1 : 0)
const fromIso = (date) =>
  date .split ('-') .map (Number)
const toIso = (y) => (m) => (d) => 
  `${y}-${String (m) .padStart (2, '0')}-${String (d) .padStart (2, '0')}`

const dateRange = ([y1, m1, d1], [y2, m2, d2]) => 
  y1 > y2 
    ? []
  : y1 < y2
    ? [
        ... dateRange ([y1, m1, d1], [y1, 12, 31]), 
        ... dateRange ([y1 + 1, 1, 1], [y2, m2, d2])
      ]
  : m1 > m2
    ? []
  : m1 < m2
    ? [
        ... dateRange ([y1, m1, d1], [y1, m1, daysInMonth (y1) (m1)]), 
        ... dateRange ([y1, m1 + 1, 1], [y2, m2, d2])
      ]
  : range (d1) (d2) .map (d => [y1, m1, d])

const getDays = (start, end) =>
  dateRange (fromIso (start), fromIso (end)) 
    .map (([y, m, d]) => toIso (y) (m) (d))


const parse = (input) =>
  input .split ('\n') 
    .filter (Boolean) 
    .map (s => s.split (', '))
    .map (([name, proj, start, end]) => ({name, proj, start, end}))

const findOverlaps = (input) => group (x => x.proj) (parse (input))
  .map (recs => group (x => x.name) (recs))
  .map (proj => proj .map (
    stints => stints .reduce (
      ({days}, {start, end, ...rest}) => ({...rest, days: unique ([... days, ...getDays (start, end)])}),
      {days: []}
    )
  ))
  .flatMap (allPairs) 
  .map (([a, b]) => ({
    proj: a.proj,
    people: [a.name, b.name],
    overlappingDays: overlap (a.days, b.days) .length,
  }))
 .filter (({overlappingDays}) => overlappingDays > 0)


const input = `
John, ASD, 2019-03-05, 2020-03-25
Martin, ASD, 2020-03-02, 2020-03-6
Frank, ASD, 2020-03-20, 2020-03-25
Frank, OI9, 2017-03-07, 2020-03-25,
Simeon, proectX, 2018-07-22, 2020-01-04
Mileena, proectX, 2020-01-01, 2021-02-03
Mileena, proectX, 2019-05-11, 2019-05-15
` 

console .log (findOverlaps (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```