# How can I check for overlapping dates in Typescript (without multiple iterations if possible)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function which declares and populates an array of dates:

```
 let dateArray: { startDate: Date, endDate: Date }[] = [];
 let dateVal = {startDate: new Date('2022-09-05'), endDate: new Date('2022-09-23')};
 dateArray.push(dateVal);
 dateVal = {startDate: new Date('2022-10-01'), endDate: new Date('2022-10-31')};
 dateArray.push(dateVal);
```

I need to check that none of the dates overlap; in the example above there is no overlap because the first date range ends on 23 September, whereas the second starts on 1 October.  However, if I add a new value:

```
 dateVal = {startDate: new Date('2022-10-21'), endDate: new Date('2022-11-14')};
 dateArray.push(dateVal)
```

then there is an overlap because it starts on 21 October which is before the end of the second value (31 October).
Can anyone think of a good way to determine if there are any overlaps in the values in dateArray?  The maximum feasible number of array elements is probably 10-20.  I can see a brute force approach but an elegant solution would be good!  Thank you.

Comment: Brute force would be the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784883/check-if-more-than-two-date-ranges-overlap) I'm guessing?

Comment: Looks like a leetcode problem, but eaiser

Comment: What does "elegant" mean? How are you going to determine which answer is the most "elegant". We purposefully attempt to keep questions objective and deterministic to avoid questions like the above. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask) for more.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - apologies; I have been having a trying time with code reviews and pull requests from someone who seeks to impress others with his command of arcane coding, whereas I am by nature rather a dull procedural kind of person.  I was trying to avoid a solution which would result in a comment "why didn't you use xxx instead?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean but not fastest way:

```js
const sortedArray = dateArray.sort((left,right)=>left.startDate.valueOf() 
- right.startDate.valueOf() 
const isOverlaped = ()=>{
  for(let index =1;index< sortedArray.length;index++){
    if(sortedArray[index-1].endDate.valueOf() - sortedArray[index].startDate.valueOf() >= 0){
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Try to use `reduce` to make it more "elegant".

```js
const sortedArray = dateArray.sort((left,right)=>left.startDate.valueOf() 
- right.startDate.valueOf()
let isOverlaped = false; 
sortedArray.reduce((left,right)=>{
  if(left.endDate.valueOf() - right.startDate.valueOf() >= 0 ){
    isOverlaped = true
  }
  return right
}) 
// you can use isOverlaped
```

Comment: Please make your answer written as if it was always the way it is currently written. If someone wants to know when something was edited it, they can view [the timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74197438/timeline).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks!  and I will edit my answer as your advice. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz I use `valueOf` to get the milliseconds of given Date, am I doing it right?

Comment: When you say "I know we can use O(N) time to implement it", are you sure? I don't see how you can get away from putting the ranges in some kind of order, which would be O(NlogN)... I'd be interested in hearing of an O(N) solution that isn't just an O(NlogN) solution in disguise.

Comment: @jcalz This is another mistake yet. I will delete this sentence. You are right.